# Merging Lines using sed

Tags: sed

I have text file that consists of 45999 lines. Each line has a word (unigram). I want to create two-sequential words (bigrams). For example:

```
apple
pie
red
vine
```

I want `'apple pie', 'pie red', 'red vine'`. I tried with `sed 'N;s/\n/ /'` but it creates just 'apple pie' and 'red vine'. How can I solve this problem? Thank you..

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helped you? @Tansu Taşçıoğlu

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  s1="\047"
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    print s1 $(i-1) s1, s1 $i s1
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
'apple','pie'
'pie','red'
'red','vine'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** since output of OP is not clear so adding this one too.

```
awk -v RS="" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  s1="\047"
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")s1 $(i-1) s1 OFS s1 $i s1
  }
}
END{
  print val
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
'apple','pie','pie','red','red','vine'
```

Comment: @Tansu Taşçıoğlu, Could you please do let me know if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 'N;s/\n(.*)/ \1&/;P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the current line, then replace the newline by a space and append the second line again. Print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. This does not print the last line as it is not a pair, if the last line is needed use:

```
sed -E 'N;s/\n(.*)/ \1&/;P;D' file
```

If the output is to be printed as a single line with each pair surrounded by single quotes and separated by a comma, use:

```
sed -E ':a;$!N;s/(\S+)\n(.*)/'\''\1 \2'\'', \2/;ta;s/ (\S+)$/ '\''\1'\''/' file
```

Or:

```
sed -E ':a;$!N;s/(\S+)\n(.*)/'\''\1 \2'\'', \2/;ta;s/, \S+$/' file
```